# object scalatest is not a member of package org [error] Cygwin

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I was wondering if I could get some help with this one. I know there are many different issues with the same title, however, after following all the instructions (I hope), I could not get it to compile still. I've been at this for over 7 hours.

This is my issue. I am using Cygwin64 terminal to do some scala programming with sbt. I run the test and make sure that the test file is in the test folder but nothing is working. I have tried to compile it without the test file and then bring it back in but it does not work either.

```
$ sbt test
[info] Loading project definition from C:\cygwin64\home\Sam\hof\project
[info] Set current project to hof (in build file:/C:/cygwin64/home/Sam/hof/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\cygwin64\home\Sam\hof\target\scala-2.10\test-classes...
[error] C:\cygwin64\home\Sam\hof\src\test\scala\TestSuite.scala:3: object scalatest is not a member of package org
[error] class TestSuite extends org.scalatest.FunSuite {
[error]                             ^
[error] C:\cygwin64\home\Sam\hof\src\test\scala\TestSuite.scala:5: not found: value test
[error]   test("map2 with add"){
[error]   ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Sep 19, 2016 1:07:10 AM
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: sbt can be painful, but not quite so much. I'm not sure what you tried. Quickest thing is to push your example project to github so someone can look at it.

Comment: Do you have something like `libraryDependencies := "org.scalatest" ...` in your `build.sbt`?

Comment: I was facing the same problem. I don't know why, but run `sbt test` in the root project instead of run it inside the `src/test/scala` solved the problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Running `sbt test` in the project root gave me the `object scalatest is not a member of package org` error. But when I changed to `src/test` directory, it completed successfully.